# edit-config is not working in config.xml in cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic app and i want to add android@autoBackup="false" in AndroidManifest.xml file through config.xml.
As per the cordova documentation, cordova version 6.4 supports edit-config tag in config.xml through which i can achieve this similar to plugin.xml.

This is what i have written in config.xml file.

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
    <application android:autoBackup="false" />
  </edit-config>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
  <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
  <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
  <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

And it changes my AndroidManifest.xml file like this

```
<application android:autoBackup="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
  <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <application android:autoBackup="false" />
  <activity android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <service android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <service android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
</application>
```

In above code of AndroidManifest.xml, you can easily find application tag has been updated with android@autoBackup="false" but also added application tag as child of first one with autoBackup attribute. 
I don't want application tag as child tag, i tried a lot but couldn't find the root cause of this issue.
Can anyone suggest me what am i doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Try changing the "target" property of the edit-config tag like this:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="application" mode="merge">
```

This tells cordova you want to modify a node named "application". See [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) for more details on XPath selectors.

If this should not work out for you can have a look at [cordova-plugin-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config). With this plugin you can simply add a preference tag to the android section of config.xml like [this](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config#android-preferences):

```
<preference name="android-manifest/@android:allowBackup" value="false" />
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but still i am getting the same issue. Suggested plugin i have used before and its working expected, but i don't want to use this plugin anymore, even i got this idea from "cordova-plugin-custom-config" plugin docs [here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config#android-preferences) .

Comment: Could you try changing the target property to `/*` or `/manifest/*`? Maybe it has to be an absolute path. May I ask whats wrong with using the custom-config plugin?

Comment: still getting the same issue after changing the target property. There is no specific reason with custom-config plugin, as we just need to add only one attribute to application tag and we are using cordova@6.4.0 now, that's why we are trying to achieve it without plugin. If nothing goes in positive, we can continue with custom-config plugin. Really appreciate for your ongoing help.

Comment: One more thing to try: Remove the slash at the end of the application tag: `<application android:autoBackup="false">`. The application root tag is not a self-closing tag and because of the merge mode it is probably not able to find one to replace and adds it instead.

Comment: In XML we need to close all tag, it could be self closed or have similar closing tag. I have tried in both way,  but there is no chance of success for me. My team is still working on to find root cause but due to time shortage we are planning to continue with custom-config plugin till we get other solution. i really appreciate for your quick response. Also i'll be monitoring all answers posted here as well. If i get any solution, i'll definitely post here. I hope you will be posting here your suggestion.

Comment: One another thing: I just tried it myself and for my project your edit-config tag is working as expected. The only thing I changed is `autoBackup` to `allowBackup`, is that just a typo or do you really want to use `autoBackup` because I don't think this property exists in the `android:` namespace. And another thing I noticed: You have a second activity tag for firebase in your AndroidManifest, maybe that is the reason. I use cordova-plugin-firebase which does not add another activity - just if you want to try to rule that reason out.

Comment: You are right, this is just a typo, i am using `allowBackup`. Currently i have `cordova-plugin-fcm` in our code, i have also tried with `cordova-plugin-firebase`, it does not add another activity but still getting `application tag` as child.

Comment: This is getting really wired! I guess you already tried deleting the whole `platforms` folder and readded the android platform? Another question: does the application still work or does it crash?

Comment: yes, i have tried with deleting platforms folder completely and added it again, still getting same error. `Another question: does the application still work or does it crash?` Yes application is working fine. There is no issue with `application tag as child`. I am assuming i have lot of cordova plugin in app, may be there is some issue with one of them, since still i don't have any exact reason, can't be sure.

Comment: As long as the application still works I don't see a problem. But you're right, kind of hard to track down with a lot of other plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. If you get any solution in future please post here, i'll do same.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I needed to add this to the widget tag: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Fix thanks to https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config/issues/24#issuecomment-172981002

Answer (score 1):

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:allowBackup="false" />
</edit-config>
```

Try this one which works for me.

Comment: Specifying the path to the AndroidManifest.xml file did it for me, using cordova-android 8.1

Answer (score 0):

for me this works:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="26" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="ShowTitle" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff2d2e2d" />
    <edit-config target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
         <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
         </application>
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

`The conflicting plugin, undefined, already modified the same attributes`

This is a definite bug in Cordova and error stating `undefined` isn't helping. In my case only one plugin was using edit-config, I cleaned up android platform, emptied plugins folder, inside package.json moved the offending plugin to top of the cordova.plugins section. This made cordova add that offending plugin before all others.

Doing this did fix the issue but on top of that it should help you identify if you have second offender in that list.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similiar problem by installing the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin and adding a `custom-preference` entry in the `config.xml` to change contents of the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Example:

```xml
[...]
<platform name="android">
  [...]
  <custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:label" value="MyAppName"/>
</platform>
```