# config-file is not working in config.xml in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

Related to [edit-config is not working in config.xml in cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554790/edit-config-is-not-working-in-config-xml-in-cordova)

```
❯ cordova --version
6.5.0
```

---

I would like to add the following configuration in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I checked [the official cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#config-file) from which is the following example

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
  <activity android:name="com.foo.Foo" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter></intent-filter>
  </activity>
</config-file>
```

So I added the following block into my `config.xml` file

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" platform="android" parent="/manifest/application/activity" mode="merge">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent-filter>
</config-file>
```

Without any success.

*Note:* I use [this plugin darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent](https://github.com/darryncampbell/darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent) that uses the `config-file` tag in its `plugin.xml` file. But the same tag does not work from a `config.xml` file.

So far so good, I tried harder with another documentation. As explained in [the deprecated plugin cordova-plugin-intent](https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent#cordova-plugin-for-accessing-the-cordova-intent-and-handling-onnewintent-android-only)

> It is recommended to use a hook or the custom config plugin to ensure that the above XML will automatically added in case you want to have a fresh checkout or remove/add the platform.

So I went to [the recommended plugin cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) also listed in [the related question about `edit-config` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554790/edit-config-is-not-working-in-config-xml-in-cordova). And [the documentation of this plugin tells me the exact same as the official cordova documentation about `config-file` tag in `config.xml`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config#do-i-need-it)

> However: recent versions of the Cordova/Phonegap CLI have added official support for  and  blocks in the config.xml (previously they only worked in plugin.xml).
>
> So if all you want to do is insert a block of native config or change a native preference, you probably don't need this plugin at all.

I succeeded to use `edit-config` to merge a custom attribute from `config.xml` to `AndroidManifest.xml` as shown below in green.

[image]

But I still don't know how to use `config-file` to update `AndroidManifest.xml` as shown above in red.

❓ So the question is: is the cordova documentation wrong about `config-file`? What is the best solution in 2018 to add custom `intent-filter` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

---

*Note about [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)*

I add in `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
  <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  <custom-config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="./application/activity">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
  </custom-config-file>
</platform>
```

And the plugin applied custom config from `config.xml` to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.darryncampbell.cordova.plugin.intent.ACTION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But the custom `intent-filter` was not appened to the `intent-filter` list, but it replaced the first one which was

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.darryncampbell.cordova.plugin.intent.ACTION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `cordova-custom-config` to set multi-sibling `<intent-filter>` elements, you must ensure they have a unique label attribute as the plugin [distinguishes them by label](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config/blob/master/hooks/applyCustomConfig.js#L126). You can see this illustrated in [the example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example/blob/master/config.xml#L81).

So something like this:

```
<custom-config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="./application/activity/[@android:name='MainActivity']">
    <intent-filter android:label="custom_filter">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</custom-config-file>
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `cordova-custom-config`

Comment: ❤️ Thank you very much for your concern! I tried out to set a `android:label` on my custom `intent-filter` tag. But the one with `android:label="@string/launcher_name"` (see details and context on my question) is still replaced.
Without it, the application is not displayed on the launcher anymore.

Comment: You may need to set the parent so it exactly matches [what the plugin is expecting](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config/blob/master/hooks/applyCustomConfig.js#L125) - see the parent attribute value in my update answer

Comment: By changing the `parent` attribute, it works like a charm! Thanks you very much!

Comment: I'm waiting to see if an answer regarding built-in support by cordova appears, otherwise I'll validate your answer that allows to move forward.

Comment: The current problem with built-in `<config-file>` support in Cordova CLI is that the `<config-file>` blocks in `config.xml` are applied before the default values that Cordova sets in the native config, which means if your `<config-file>` blocks modify the same parts of the native config as Cordova's default settings, your changes will get wiped out when Cordova sets its defaults. `cordova-custom-config` works around this by applying changes on the `after_prepare` hook, i.e. after Cordova

Answer (score 0):

(this would be a comment but I don't have enough rep)

I confirm: `<config-file>` does not work on Cordova 7.0 (although `<edit-config>` does), see my **config.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget ...>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/manifest/application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <test1 />
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="./application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <test2 />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
```

... is completely ignored.

Simply installing the **cordova-custom-config** solved the issue. 
You need to use only relative XPath like `./application` though, otherwise you get an error:

```
cordova-custom-config: Error updating config for platform 'android': Cannot use absolute path on element
```