# Cordova android build :app:processDebugResources failed

Tags: android, cordova

I woke up this morning, no code has been committed or pushed and I attempted to run a build but suddenly my build failed to give me the following error:

[image]

I tried updating `Android Studio` but that didn't work.

I looked online to check this `android:attr/lStar` but I could only find something related to `react` which I'm not using (my project is an `Ionic angular application`)

I am really puzzled about this has anyone tried this before?

I am using `Cordova`  and the android version is `9.0.0`

**Abit more info**

This is built using the command `cordova build android` the command that files is:

```
/Users/admin/myagent/_work/3/s/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/admin/myagent/_work/3/s/platforms/android/build.gradle
```

so `cdvBuildDebug -b`

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Just open your app/build.gradle file and change this line.

```
androidx.core:core-ktx:+
```

replace with

```
androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0
```

Here is an Example:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    androidXCore = "1.6.0"
}
```

**Solution 2**

upgrade the compile SDK to Android 31
If you are using androidx.core:core-ktx:+ then this will find the latest version of androidx.core:core-ktx:+ and the latest one is 1.7.0 and the latest version needs the Android 31 compile SDK. So that You are facing this issue.

Here is Two Possible Solution:

1- use a specific version, use androidx.core:core-ktx:${version} instead of androidx.core:core-ktx:+

2- upgrade the compile SDK to Android 31

for more information you can see this article from [here](https://exerror.com/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks-workersactionfacade/).

Comment: in my app/build.gradle file i dont have any where where it says ktx or androidCore :S I have updated my build tools in android sdk

Comment: i have updated my question with a bit more info

Comment: if you couldn't find `androidx.core:core-ktx:+` can you check for  `ext ` object and add the `androidXCore = "1.6.0"` to it, I had this problem from a few months in my ionic app and that's how I fix it can you check it?

Comment: i added it but got same error :(

Comment: I found this question that have a similar issue you can check it and I'll search for it to help as much as I could I know this errors can drive someone crazy :(

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021225/resource-linking-fails-on-lstar/69395334#69395334

Comment: Loauy so i found the problem in the android folder there is a file name project.properties where there was this + sign in front of a version this file is generated with cordova do you know how I can edit that so that cordova generates a correct file?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you can use `edit-config` method to edit the file using `config.xml` you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554790/edit-config-is-not-working-in-config-xml-in-cordova

Comment: Or you can try to check what is the plugin that add it to your project and make a patch for it so it'll work everytime without need to edit.

Comment: the plugin is called androidx.appcompat:appcompat do you know how I can change this so I don't have to do it every time it updates

Comment: solution2 was the way to go for me! thanks thousand times!!